# How to preserve the full state of objects between scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

When loading a new Scene I run into the trouble of having my mouse drag not carry over to the next scene and having to re-click when the new scene is loaded.

I would like the mouse click to carry over seamlessly to the next scene without the player noticing and more generally I would like to know how best to preserve certain game objects and make them carry over to the next scene.

In essence, what I'm trying to do is have the entire game act like one big scene that the player can play trough but still be broken down into smaller scenes that could be accessed or transformed into levels at a later stage.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code I'm currently using

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;

public class MoveBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {    
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = mousePos;   

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);     
    }
}
```

Bellow is the script that is responsible for the loading of the scene:

```
public class StarCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool alreadyScored = false;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        alreadyScored = false;
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball"))
        {
            if (!alreadyScored)
            {
                ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
                StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());

                alreadyScored = true;
            }

        }

        if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }

    }


    private IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {

        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.yellow;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.white;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show/explain how exactly you are loading your scenes? I'm pretty sure you could solve the issue by placing this dragged object into a "DragScene" which always remains there and then use Additive Scene loading and unloading for the other scenes.

Comment: @derHugo I just updated the code and added the script responsible for the scene chagne

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main reason why it doesn't work is that you probably also have another `Camera` in the new Scene.

The `OnMouseDrag` rely on the Physics system internally using the objects `Collider` and raycasts from the `Camera`. Now if you switch Scene I'ld guess the one Camera gets disabled so your drag gets interrupted.

Also using `LoadScene` instead of `LoadSceneAsync` causes a visible lag and might also be related to the issue.

---

I have a maybe a bit more complex solution but that is what I usually do:

#### 1. Have one Global Scene "MainScene"

This Scene contains stuff like e.g. the MainCamera, global ligthning, global manager components that should never be destroyed anyway.

#### 2. Use additive async Scene loading

You said you do not want your user to not note when the scene switches so I would recommend using [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) anyway.

Then in order to **not** unload the before mentioned `MainScene` you pass the [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) [`LoadSceneMode.Additive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html). This makes the new Scene be loaded additional to the already present one. Then later you only have to exchange those by unloading the previously additive loaded scene.

I created a very simple `static` manager for this:

```
public static class MySceneManager
{
    // store build index of last loaded scene
    // in order to unload it later
    private static int lastLoadedScene = -1;

    public static void LoadScene(int index, MonoBehaviour caller)
    {
        caller.StartCoroutine(loadNextScene(index));
    }

    // we need this to be a Coroutine (see link below)
    // in order to correctly set the SceneManager.SetActiveScene(newScene);
    // after the scene has finished loading. So the Coroutine is required 
    // in order to wait with it until the reight moment
    private static IEnumerator loadNextScene(int index)
    {
        // start loading the new scene async and additive
        var _async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(index, LoadSceneMode.Additive);

        // optionally prevent the scene from being loaded instantly but e.g.
        // display a loading progress
        // (in your case not but for general purpose I added it)
        _async.allowSceneActivation = false;
        while (_async.progress < 0.9f)
        {
            // e.g. show progress of loading

            // yield in a Coroutine means
            // "pause" the execution here, render this frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        _async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        // loads the remaining 10% 
        // (meaning it runs all the Awake and OnEnable etc methods)
        while (!_async.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        // at this moment the new Scene is supposed to be fully loaded

        // Get the new scene
        var newScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(index);

        // would return false if something went wrong during loading the scene
        if (!newScene.IsValid()) yield break;

        // Set the new scene active
        // we need this later in order to place objects back into the correct scene
        // if we do not want them to be DontDestroyOnLoad anymore
        // (see explanation in SetDontDestroyOnLoad)
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(newScene);

        // Unload the last loaded scene
        if (lastLoadedScene >= 0) SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(lastLoadedScene);

        // update the stored index
        lastLoadedScene = index;
    }
}
```

This `MySceneManager` is a `static class` so it is not attached to any GameObject or Scene but simply "lives" in the `Assets`. You can now call it from anywhere using

```
 MySceneManager.LoadScene(someIndex, theMonoBehaviourCallingIt);
```

The second parameter of type `MonoBehaviour` (so basically your scripts) is required because someone has to be responsible for running the `IEnumerator` [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which can't be done by the `static class` itself.

#### 3. DontDestroyOnLoad

Currently you are adding any GameObject you dragged at any time to `DontDestroyOnLoad`. But you never undo this so anything you touched meanwhile will be carried on from that moment ... forever.

I would rather use e.g. something like

```
public static class GameObjectExtensions
{
    public static void SetDontDestroyOnLoad(this GameObject gameObject, bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            // Note in general if DontDestroyOnLoad is called on a child object
            // the call basically bubbles up until the root object in the Scene
            // and makes this entire root tree DontDestroyOnLoad
            // so you might consider if you call this on a child object to first do
            //gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
            UnityEngine.Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            // add a new temporal GameObject to the active scene
            // therefore we needed to make sure before to set the
            // SceneManager.activeScene correctly
            var newGO = new GameObject();
            // This moves the gameObject out of the DontdestroyOnLoad Scene
            // back into the currently active scene
            gameObject.transform.SetParent(newGO.transform, true);
            // remove its parent and set it back to the root in the 
            // scene hierachy
            gameObject.transform.SetParent(null, true);
            // remove the temporal newGO GameObject
            UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(newGO);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an [Extension Method](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) which allows you to simply call

```
someGameObject.SetDontDestroyOnLoad(boolvalue);
```

on any GameObject reference.

Then I changed your script to

```
public class MoveBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();

    // On mouse down enable DontDestroyOnLoad
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        gameObject.SetDontDestroyOnLoad(true);
    }

    // Do your dragging part here
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        // NOTE: Your script didn't work for me
        // in ScreenToWorldPoint you have to pass in a Vector3
        // where the Z value equals the distance to the 
        // camera/display plane
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
            Input.mousePosition.x,
            Input.mousePosition.y,
            transform.position.z)));
        transform.position = mousePos;
    }

    // On mouse up disable DontDestroyOnLoad
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        gameObject.SetDontDestroyOnLoad(false);
    }
}
```

And in your `StarCollision` script you only have to exchange

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
```

with

```
MySceneManager.LoadScene(2, this);
```

---

#### Demo

For a little demonstration I "faked" it using two simple scripts

This one in the Main scene

```
public class LoadFirstscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        MySceneManager.LoadScene(1, this);
    }
}
```

And this one in the other scenes

```
public class LoadNextScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int nexSceneIndex;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) return;

        MySceneManager.LoadScene(nexSceneIndex, this);
    }
}
```

And have 3 Scenes:

- Main: As mentioned contains

  - the MainCamera
  - a DirectionalLight
  - the `LoadFirstScene`

  [image]
- test: contains

  - a `MoveBall` "Sphere"
  - the `LoadNextScene`

  [image]
- test2: contains

  - a MoveBall "Cube"
  - the `LoadNextScene`

  [image]

With the indexes matching the build settings (make sure `Main` is always at `0` ;) )

[image]

I can now switch between `test` and `test2` using the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

If I drag one of the objects meanwhile I can carry it on into the next scene (but only 1 at a time). I can even take it on again back to the first scene in order to have e.g. two sphere objects I can play with ;)

[image]

Comment: I just had a question regarding your solution. After implementing everything I now get to seemlesly move my object over to the next scene. However one issue I run into and don't seem to find a solution for is that the gameobjects in the new scene don't seem to be able to interact or react to references made in script to them to do something with regard to the white ball I moved over from the previous screen. Do you possibly know why that might be the case?

Comment: for example if I ask them to go to the current position of the white ball nothing happens, they spawn but remain static, eventough the script tells them to move towards that position

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly .. maybe you should open a new question and provide the according code. In general ofcourse scene references are difficult to restore. You could in the moment you drag an object additionally add a certain `Tag` to it so you could use `FindObjectWithTag` in order to get a reference to the dragged object in the scenes

Comment: Thats what I'm currently doing. in my first scene I have a script attached too a gameobject from that scene that spawns certain gameobjects and makes them behave in a certain way as soon as the score increment triggers a change in scene I have a second script attached to a game object that makes the same gameobjects previously mentioned spawn however the behaviour of these objects is determined by the same script regardless of the scene. But it doesn't seem to react anymore when the scene switches I will open a new question to show this

Comment: Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012688/gameobjects-spawned-in-a-new-scene-dont-seem-to-react-to-a-gameobject-carried-o